# Project build failed after adding a new dependency indicating Duplicate class

Tags: android, gradle, libraries

I was working on my application all was fine, until I wanted to add a barcode scanner, when I added this `implementation 'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'`

my application started to fail building with this error:

```
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout found in 
modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) and 
classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$1 found in 
modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) and 
classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$DefaultBehavior found in 
modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) and 
classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$DispatchChangeEvent found in 
modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) and 
classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$HierarchyChangeListener 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener found in 
modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) and 
classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$SavedState 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$SavedState$1 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)
Duplicate class 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$ViewElevationComparator 
found in modules classes.jar (com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0) 
and classes.jar (com.android.support:design:27.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

of course the Go to Documentation link doesn't take me anywhere.

also here is my gradle dependecies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:9.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:9.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation `'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'`
}
```

when i remove the `'info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'` Dependency, it builds fine (but i need it).
i don't know what to remove, or what to do, any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved when i added this dependecies explicitly:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to transitive dependency, you've two version of same artifact.

Exclude `com.android.support` group from `barcode-reader` artifact.

```
implementation ('info.androidhive:barcode-reader:1.1.5'){
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```